# Print out the left view of a Binary Tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion

The task is to write a function that prints the "left view" (nodes visible when tree is viewed from left side.) of a binary tree.

For example, the left view of following tree is 1 2 4 8

```
          1
       /     \
     2        3
   /   \     /  \
  4     5   6    7
                  \
                   8
```

I'd like to see other people's solutions.

Comment: what is your solution?

Comment: I added my implementation of an algorithm from a book.

Answer (score 1):

My solution uses recursion. (C#)

```
    private static int globalDepth = 0;
    public static void PrintLeftSide (Node root, int localDepth)
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (localDepth > globalDepth)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(root.Value);
            globalDepth++;
        }
        PrintLeftSide(root.Left, localDepth + 1);
        PrintLeftSide(root.Right, localDepth + 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was asked this question in an interview, except in my case the question was to return the *right* side view instead of the left, and instead of printing the values return them as a list. Here is my implementation in C# using a Queue instead of recursion. A `Tuple` is used so that each node has an associated `int` which is the level it's at in the tree.

```
public static List<int> RightSideView(TreeNode root)
{
    List<int> lstRightSide = new List<int>();
    Tuple<TreeNode, int> cur;
    Queue<Tuple<TreeNode, int>> q = new Queue<Tuple<TreeNode, int>>();
    int prevLevel = -1;
    if (root != null) { q.Enqueue(new Tuple<TreeNode, int>(root, 0)); }

    while (q.Count > 0)
    {
        do
        {
            cur = q.Dequeue();

            if (cur.Item2 == prevLevel)
            {
                if (cur.Item1.right != null)
                { q.Enqueue(new Tuple<TreeNode, int>(cur.Item1.right, cur.Item2 + 1)); }

                if (cur.Item1.left != null)
                { q.Enqueue(new Tuple<TreeNode, int>(cur.Item1.left, cur.Item2 + 1)); }
            }
        } while (cur.Item2 == prevLevel);

        lstRightSide.Add(cur.Item1.val);

        if (cur.Item1.right != null)
        { q.Enqueue(new Tuple<TreeNode, int>(cur.Item1.right, cur.Item2 + 1)); }

        if (cur.Item1.left != null)
        { q.Enqueue(new Tuple<TreeNode, int>(cur.Item1.left, cur.Item2 + 1)); }

        prevLevel++;
    }

    return lstRightSide;
}
```

I will say your solution is more elegant, this just shows a different possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without using global variable. While calling, the *currentLevel* parameter value would be set to 1 and *maxLevel* value to 0

```
    public static int LeftView(TreeNode node, int currentLevel, int maxLevel)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return 0;

        if (currentLevel > maxLevel)
        { 
            Console.Write(node.Value + " ");
            maxLevel = currentLevel;
        }

        var leftLevel = LeftView(node.Left, currentLevel + 1, maxLevel);

        maxLevel = maxLevel > leftLevel ? maxLevel : leftLevel;

        var rightLevel = LeftView(node.Right, currentLevel + 1, maxLevel);

        return maxLevel > rightLevel? maxLevel:rightLevel;
    }
```